# Left/Right Arrows not Moving

Tags: jquery, html, slider, carousel

I am trying to make some image carousal... Layout was done.. Not understood how to move it.. I am thinking some jquery is missing.. Tried with many codes but no luck.. I am not looking for any auto scrolling, i am trying to make some simple carousal when it clicks only it move left or side..

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="slider slider-category">
    <div class="slider-clip">
        <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 1248px;">
            <div class="bx-viewport" aria-live="polite" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 317px;">
                <ul class="slides" style="width: 24215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-845px, 0px, 0px);">

                    <li class="slide bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; margin-right: 30px; width: 251.667px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="slide-image">
                            <a href="#"><img src="#" data-src="https://eu.frette.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/225x225/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/F/3FR2954E2400_BE03_02_2_1_44.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Bicolore Linen Sheet Set by Frette"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-content">
                            <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Bicolore Linen Sheet Set</a></h4>
                            <p class="slide-price">€1,650 - €1,700</p>
                            <div class="promo_text"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="slide bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; margin-right: 30px; width: 251.667px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="slide-image">
                            <a href="#"><img src="#" data-src="https://eu.frette.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/225x225/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/F/3FR5754E2400_B101_02_85.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Macram&amp;eacute; Pizzo Sheet Set by Frette"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-content">
                            <h4 class="slide-title"><a href="#">Macramé Pizzo Sheet Set</a></h4>
                            <p class="slide-price">€1,500 - €1,550</p>
                            <div class="promo_text"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="slide bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; margin-right: 30px; width: 251.667px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="slide-image">
                            <a href="#"><img src="#" data-src="https://eu.frette.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/225x225/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/F/3FR6165E2400_BN17_02_65.jpg" width="225" height="225" alt="Sirmione Sheet Set by Frette"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-content">
                            <h4 class="slide-title">
                                <a href="#">Sirmione Sheet Set</a>
                            </h4>
                            <div>
                                <p class="slide-price slide-price-old">€425 - €450</p>
                                <p class="slide-price slide-price-new">€212.50 - €225</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="promo_text"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction">
                <div class="bx-controls-direction">
                    <a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a>
                    <a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you checked browser cosole for missing jquery information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a demo below with navigation. Try with the snippet

and if you want to remove the text there `prevText:"",  nextText:"",` change the code like this way

```css
.cover {
 position:relative;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
.cover .bx-next {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 background:#000;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:45%;
 z-index:99;
}
.cover .bx-prev {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 background:#000;
 position:absolute;
 left:15px;
 top:45%;
 z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/google-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/google-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/google-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  prevText:"prev",
  nextText:"next",
  pager:false
});
</script>
```